# how to place an image at a specified pixel of other image on a webpage

Tags: javascript, css

I want to place an image of a flag at a specified place of an image of a map
The map is big enough and only a part of map image is shown at a time using jquery slider.

I need to place the flag dynamically and I only know the pixels of where it is to be placed.

**How to place the flag at a specified pixel of the map image?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use absolute positioning as illustrated in the example below.

Put your map image in a block level container with `position: relative`.

Use absolute position to place your flag elements where you need them.

The `.flag` elements can contain your flag image, either as a background image,
a font icon or an inline image.

If you are creating the `.flag` elements dynamically, you can use inline styles to
set the top/left offsets.  I used classes for illustation only.

```css
.mapPanel {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  }
.mapPanel > img {
  display: block;
  }
.mapPanel .flag {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  }
.mapPanel .f1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  }
.mapPanel .f2 {
  top: 400px;
  left: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mapPanel">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/500">
  <span class="flag f1"></span>
  <span class="flag f2"></span>
</div>
```